# Python xpath() doesn´t display the content

Tags: python, html, xpath

I want to display certain part of web page by using xpath() function, but it returns empty list only. There should be some text, but it returns only "[]" in to the console.

Here is part of my code:

```
page = requests.get("http://10.0.0.3/admin/speedtest.php")
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
speed = tree.xpath('//*[@id="all-queries"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]')
print(speed)
```

I want to print out result of measurement on my Raspberry Pi from a table on the web page. (I copyied exact XPATH from the web site.)

I have also this part of the code, where is everything working just fine:

```
page = requests.get("http://10.0.0.3/admin/speedtest.php")
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
heading = tree.xpath('//a[@id="temperature"]/text()')
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Can you provide the relevant parts of the HTML?

Comment: @zx485 its running on localhost on raspberry.. or, I dont understand what do you mean.

Comment: Have you examined `page.content` yourself to ensure the desired element is present?  Is that element created with dynamic Javascript?

Comment: He means that without seeing the actual page content, we can't know why the xpath isn't working.

Comment: @John Gordon As I said, part of the code is working, just this part inside of the table  is returning empty list.

Comment: @John Gordon Yes, I see everything on the web:  https://snag.gy/SIfhot.jpg

Comment: Seeing the value in a browser is very different from seeing it in the page html content.  We need to see the actual html of the page.

Comment: `requests` is not a browser.  It does not do a lot of things browser do, such as execute javascript.  Is that element supposed to be created by dynamic javascript?

Comment: @John Gordon Is this enough? https://snag.gy/ZSh4W0.jpg And lets say, that I want to print out the "downloand speed or upload speed."

Comment: @John Gordon probably yes, because I can copy JS path. But what is interesting, part of my code is working with the temperature whis supposed to be JS also.

Comment: Check for some iframes which might need handling in order to work.